# Will Catalina stream movies (etc) to a 3rd Generation Apple TV box?

Tags: itunes, catalina, appletv, home-sharing

I have one of the older, 3rd generation Apple TV boxes, (the sort that came with a clicky remote, not a swipey one). I regularly use it to watch movies and TV shows served up by a Mac currently running High Sierra (I *think*… might be Mojave), via iTunes with home sharing.

Given that iTunes is a thing of the past in Catalina, will this set up still work if I upgrade the Mac to MacOS 10.15?

Answer (score 1):

If I'm correct, programs like quicktime player, Apple TV and more, offer airplay in the app itself. I know your movies(if bought on itunes), moved to the Apple tv app on your macbook. If you start playing, see the airplay button on the bottom left corner! [image]

Comment: Yeah, they do offer that Airplay function — have done so for a few OS versions now — but I don't believe that it's quite the same thing. The difference is one of what's controlling what. With Airplay the device (iPhone, Mac, whatever) chooses to stream to the Apple TV — so the device is the initiator and is pushing the content. The function I'm thinking of is where the Apple TV can access the iTunes library on a networked computer with Home Sharing turned on, so in that situation the Apple TV box is the initiator and is pulling the content to itself and Airplay is not involved (AFAIK).

Comment: To put it another way, in Scenario A (Airplay), the Mac or iPhone is specifying the Apple TV box as a _destination_. In Scenario B (HomeSharing) Apple TV is specifying the iTunes library as a _source_. It is scenario B that I am interested in, since it draws content from an iTunes library and iTunes won't exist in Catalina. And, being older hardware, maybe the Apple TV box will get confused.